# Make it so that columns are always on one row

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

When the screen is big, everything is how it's supposed to look. The problem comes when you are using a phone. I would like these two columns to ALWAYS be on one row, but right now if you are on mobile the columns will stack. How can I make it so that they just resize and stay on one row no matter the size of the screen? I would like the first column(left one) to be the one that gets resized.

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <div class="form-group mb-3">
                <label asp-for=Title></label>
                <input readonly class="form-control form-control-lg" asp-for=Title placeholder="Title"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mb-3">
                <label asp-for=Description></label>
                <textarea readonly class="form-control" asp-for=Description rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mb-3">
                <label asp-for=Price></label>
                <input readonly class="form-control" asp-for=Price/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mb-3">
                <label asp-for=Location></label>
                <input readonly class="form-control" asp-for=Location/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mb-3">
                <label asp-for="CategoryName"></label>
                <input readonly class="form-control" asp-for="CategoryName" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mb-3">
                <label asp-for="DateCreatedOn"></label>
                <input readonly class="form-control" asp-for="DateCreatedOn" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="card border border-primary rounded p-0 mb-3 mx-1">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <img id="image1" src="@profilePictureSrc" class="card-img">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer text-center">
                        <input readonly class="form-control text-center" asp-for="UserName"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using bootstrap, according to https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/grid/ you just have to change from lg to the breakpoint you want

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-8">
      <div class="form-group mb-3">
        <label asp-for=Title></label>
        <input readonly class="form-control form-control-lg" asp-for=Title placeholder="Title" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group mb-3">
        <label asp-for=Description></label>
        <textarea readonly class="form-control" asp-for=Description rows="3"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group mb-3">
        <label asp-for=Price></label>
        <input readonly class="form-control" asp-for=Price/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group mb-3">
        <label asp-for=Location></label>
        <input readonly class="form-control" asp-for=Location/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group mb-3">
        <label asp-for="CategoryName"></label>
        <input readonly class="form-control" asp-for="CategoryName" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group mb-3">
        <label asp-for="DateCreatedOn"></label>
        <input readonly class="form-control" asp-for="DateCreatedOn" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="card border border-primary rounded p-0 mb-3 mx-1">
          <div class="card-body">
            <img id="image1" src="https://picsum.photos/200" class="card-img">
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer text-center">
            <input readonly class="form-control text-center" asp-for="UserName" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```